# Basic partitioning in PlayORM

Tags: playorm

Assume that I have a CF in cassandra that has following schema:

- TimeStamp
- Device ID
- Device Name
- Device Owner

PKEY (TimeStamp, Device ID): This means partition is happening on TimeStamp.

Following are the queries I'm interested in:

Select * from schema where TimeStamp='..'
Select * from schema where DeviceID='..'

First query returns 500K records, second query returns 50K records. For first query, the bottleneck is all fetch on a single node, so I want to distribute data on multiple nodes for a TimeStamp. The bottleneck for second query is that all the records may be distributed all over the disks on different nodes, resulting in several disk fetches.

Now assume that I want to create virtual partitions, such that entries for a particular TimeStamp are also distributed across cluster nodes. Is this possible in PlayORM? If yes, can you please provide code which can do so (or example which does such a thing)?

Another requirement that I have is to search all the records for a particular Device ID. Can I do virtual partitioning on 'Device ID' for the same CF? If yes, can you please provide code/link which tells how to do it?

I'd be glad if some one could provide the source code for doing some thing like this, because documentation are not so easy to comprehend, and writing code simply by reading the current documentation is turning out to be a nightmare. Without 'complete' code examples, evaluating PlayORM seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you would need something like this in PlayOrm...(post a comment if I am missing anything and I can respond again).

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/blob/master/src/test/java/com/alvazan/test/db/PartitionedTrade.java

and also the query 
     PARTITIONS t('account', :partId) SELECT t FROM TABLE as t INNER JOIN t.security as s WHERE s.securityType = :type and t.numShares = :shares"

'account' identifies the partition column and :partId is the id of the partition.  In your case, you would have PARTITIONS t('deviceid', {actualDeviceId}) or t('time', {time}) where the first param is the column name and the second is the actual id of the partition for time or the id of the partition for device.  Realize partitions should not have more than X millions of rows where X is probably around 3 million.

The package com.alvazan.test.db have tons of different examples and the com.alvazan.test shows how they are used.  I am going to ask someone to tweak the docs based on your feedback to put links directly to the code in our codebase......

ps. if you download from github, run gradlew eclipse OR gradle eclipse(depending on OS), and then import into eclipse, all the tests work out of the box with an in-memory noSQL version(we use that for development).  Then if you want to run against cassandra, in the docs it has how to change one line and all tests run against cassandra.

Speedup.  PlayOrm does a wide-row using the composite-name pattern for each partition(index per partition).  When you query, it reads this row in batches of 200(or the size you provide), and then sends out requests using the keys found in the index to all machines(ie. you get parallel throughput at this point).  This is because every partition is spread across the cluster.  In fact, all nodes end up with slices of nearly all partitions well depending on how many nodes you have and how many partitions(ie. 100 nodes and 32 partitions, not all nodes will have all partitions).

Under the covers playorm is doing something really really simple.  All rows are written as if they were not partitioned at all!!!  Then the index row is written(RF=3 means to 3 nodes) and the index row name is /TABLE/partition/column/partitionId.  That is the row key for the index.  With the command line tool, you can even read the index yourself and just the index or query the partition.  USe playOrm's command line tool for this.

Lastly, since wide rows in cassandra are ordered, when you use a specific index like 
    PARTITIONS d('deviceid', 'device1') select d from TABLE as d where d.time > Integer.MIN_INT

then the results come back in order of that index(ie. time in this case), or if you want reverse order, just call cursor.afterLast then cursor.previous, cursor.previous etc. etc.

To be clear, PlayOrm ignores cassandra partitioning on purpose here.  It writes in your data just like there is no partition at all.  It also writes in an index or two.  Let's say you partition twice, once by time and once by device id.  In this case it writes to the StringIndice or IntegerIndice table(BigInteger!!! not Integer) with row keys (and say your entity is called Devices).  Let's also say in your entity, you have @NoSqlIndexed on the "name" column!!!!

```
/Devices/byDevice/device1/name = the wide row
/Devices/byTime/time56/name = the wide row
```

If you have more @NoSqlIndexed columns, there is more rows in the index tables.  All rows however are spread across the cluster and do NOT care about partitioning.

Does this make sense?  Feel free to give it a shot and try it out.  Just post a new question on stackoverflow if you have any issues/questions on implementing it.

Comment: Dean, I would like to know how would PlayORM make sure that both the queries run fast? Assume you've 500 K Devices, and for each device, we've 10 K timeStamps.

Can you run me through how the partitioning should be done in cassandra for above schema, and how virtual partitioning should happen. Lets say I've a 3 node cassandra cluster, then can you give me speedup factor because of PlayORM as compared to original performance? And can you please let me know why that speed up happens?

Comment: Dean, for each 'timeStamp', there are 500 K records. When partition was done with Cassandra on timestamp, isn't that similar to PlayORM's PARTITIONS t('timestamp' , {time}) ? The problem that I have is that in Cassandra, all records of a partition (happens to be records of a timestamp in this case) goes inside a node. This causes slowdown, since the response is bottlenecked by single disk. Is PlayORM's PARTITION solution better? I believe if all records for a partition on a timestamp are distributed on all the nodes of the cluster, that solution would be most efficient.

Comment: Also, can you explain how cassandra stores all the data just once (without replication), yet PlayORM is able to create multiple partitions on different columns of a CF? This sounds too good to be true. Can you give some insights into how different partitions are actually stored in Cassandra, and if all records of a partition are stored in a single node? I'm finding it difficult convincing myself that more than one partition can happen on a CF, when a partition has all the records on a particular node of the cluster. Any link to architecture of PlayORM's virtual partitioning would be helpful.

Comment: I added more detail.  Sorry, I was out yesterday and my backup was out as well.

Comment: Also, be warned that you need to use NetworkTopology in 1.2.2 cassandra or it does not do dynamic snitch correctly meaning a slow node makes all the clients slow.  We are about to roll out a switch from SimpleTopology to Network Topology due to this issue(we filed a cassandra bug as they told us that was supposed to be working).

Comment: astyanax also correctly avoids the slow nodes when configured correctly.  We just rolled a fix two weeks ago into playorm so playorm avoids the slow nodes if using the default astyanax(since you can inject your own astyanax into us as well if you want full power on astyanax configuration).

Comment: Dean, you're internally going to store the 'original' data in Cassandra. I'd like to know which column you use to partition the data? My hunch would be that you probably are using a unique sequence (may be random), which acts as the primary key of the schema as well as its partitionID. Let's say I want to partition (using PlayORM) by columns A and B. In that case would your cassandra partitionID (and PKEY) be different than say when I want to partition (using playORM) on columns A, B and C?
From what I could make out, you're doing a lot of work in application to parallelize the queries. Kudos

Comment: I added more info to the answer at the bottom.  I hope that helps. and yes we store the original data in cassandra.  we use whatever column you tell us to use with the @NoSqlPartitionedByField annotation(and support more than one of these...the more you use though, the more writes we do which can slow you down a bit).